# How to mock a specific method of Grails Domain class?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

I'm trying to test a service which calls method `getUrl()` on my domain class:

Service class:

```
PersonService {

  //WE WANT TO TEST THIS METHOD. 
  String getPersonLink(Person person){
     person.url
  }
}

class Person {

   static transient LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator

   String name 
   String uniqueId

   static transients = ['url']

   String getUrl() {
     grailsLinkGenerator.createLink(controller:'xyz', action: 'index', id: uniqueId)
   }
}
```

I get the `NullPointerException` (it finds the `grailsLinkGenerator` as null) when I run my test.

So, I understand that I need to mock this `getUrl()` method in my domain class.

How can we mock this method call for my unit testing?

Comment: You need to share the test You've problem with. Without it, it's difficult to say. But I suppose You just need to create mock of `PersonService`.

Answer (score 3):

- you have to remove the `static`. You can't autowire a static. If you write `LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator` you will have to add `grailsLinkGenerator` to the transients. Otherwise hibernate will try to save it. You can avoid this by simply writing `def grailsLinkGenerator`.
- there is no `createLink()` method, it is called `link()`.
- in the unit test the beans are not autowired. You have to set `grailsLinkGenerator` yourself with something like this:

  ```
  def p = new Person()
  p.grailsLinkGenerator = Mock(LinkGenerator)
  ```

  then you can stub/mock `link()` (not sure what you want to test so this is just an example):

  ```
  p.grailsLinkGenerator.link (_) >> "foo"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the correcting me: It's actually a link() method and not createLink(), I ll edit it.

My concern is that I am supposed to mock each and every instance of Person. This is something I would like to avoid (if possible).

Comment: Hard to tell..  it depends on your context. Typically you should not have so many tests that really require the getUrl() method. If a test doesn't call getUrl() you don't need to set grailsLinkGenerator. I would probably move link creation (ie. the dependency on grailsLinkGenerator) out of Person. Maybe to a "PersonUrlBuilder" or something like that. Person doesn't look like the right place to me.